# git svn and do not download some files

Tags: git-svn

I would like to clone a SVN repository with `git-svn`, and without downloading some -- unuseful for me -- 'huge' files (recognized by the extension because they are not all in the same folder).

`git-update-index --assume-unchanged` or `git-gc` allow to compress the local repository, but the files are downloaded.

Is it possible to use something like `sparse-checkout` with `git-svn` ?
or what is a solution to avoid to download some files with `git-svn` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--ignore-paths` option of `git-svn` may help you.